# Java : Timer get paused by PopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, timer

Hi,
I'm working on a small program in Java that have 2 things :

- An always-on-top **JWindow** with a refresh **Timer** (there can be more than one JWindow)
- A **TrayIcon** with a **PopupMenu** on left click

The PopupMenu is opened with a **MouseEventListener** and with a dummy **Frame** as parent (needed).

Runnable example :

```java
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestWindow extends JWindow {

    private int color;

    public static Image createImage(String path) {
        URL imageURL = TestWindow.class.getResource(path);

        if (imageURL == null) {
            System.err.println("Resource not found: " + path);
            return null;
        } else {
            return (new ImageIcon(imageURL)).getImage();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addTrayIcon();
        new TestWindow();
    }

    public static void addTrayIcon(){
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(createImage("/icon.png"));
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        popup.add(new MenuItem("test"));
        popup.add(new MenuItem("test"));
        popup.add(new MenuItem("test"));

        Frame frame = new Frame("MiniMario");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setType(Frame.Type.UTILITY);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setAutoRequestFocus(true);
        frame.add(popup);
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                            popup.show(frame, e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        });

        final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public TestWindow(){
        this.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        color = 0;
        Timer refresh = new Timer(10,new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                color+=10;
                setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(color%256,color%256,color%256));
            }

        });
        this.setVisible(true);
        refresh.start();
    }

}
```

Here is the thing : when I open the PopupMenu, it freeze the JWindow. I figured out that it was the refresh timer not running anymore. I already tried the following :

- Giving up on the always-on-top
- Showing the PopupMenu in a runnable (new Thread(...).start / SwingUtilities.invokeLater / EventQueue.invokeLater)
- Replacing the JWindow Swing Timer by a Thread with an infinite loop and Thread.sleep
- Using the native TrayIcon.setPopup (it was originally the case)
- Use the JWindow or the Frame setModalExclusionType (see below)

After searching for this kind of problem, few were linked to swing modality but I don't get how to use modality on this setup because neither Frame nor PopupMenu have the setModal I saw on another post. Do I have to make my own PopupMenu out of a JDialog ?

(Sorry for my bad english)

Thank you for your time

EDIT : Runnable example

Comment: I have a runnable example which works fine.  You're going to have to provide a [fully runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before anyone is going to able to have a chance to help you

Comment: Caution:  Running this program may be dangerous to epileptics.